# Extra alignment tab changed to \cr in Deluxetable

Tags: tables, aastex, deluxetable

I have tried to find my extra column, `&`, `\\`, etc. but i am getting an error on the line with `\enddata` saying `Extra alignment tab changed to \cr` and i am getting warnings at each tablenotetext saying `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected` ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}llrlrlrlrlr}
\tablecaption{K-S Test Probabilities \label{table:KS}}
\tablewidth{0pc}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablehead
{
\colhead{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\rm{med}}_{\sigma}$}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\rm{Gott}}_{\sigma}$\  \tablenotemark{c}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\rm{wm+}}_{\sigma}$}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\rm{wm-}}_{\sigma}$}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\rm{mean}}_{\sigma}$}
&\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
\colhead{PDF}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}
}
\startdata
Gaussian & 1 & 69.4 & 1 & 53.4 & 1 & 11.9 & 1 & 11.7 & 1 & 27.9\\
Gaussian & 0.85 & 99.5 & 1.24 & 99.6 & 1.68 & 99.9 & 1.73 & 99.8 & 0.76 & 97.9\\
Laplace & 1 & 39.0 & 1 & 82.6 & 1 & 47.9 & 1 & 45.3 & 1 & 19.7\\
Laplace & 0.77 & 93.6 & 1.13 & 97.7 & 1.40 & 99.8 & 1.52 & 99.9 & 0.70 & 90.4\\
Cauchy & 1 & 4.1 & 1 & 32.8 & 1 & 64.6 & 1 & 88.7 & 1 & 1.9\\
Cauchy & 0.51 & 84.6 & 0.70 & 84.8 & 0.77 & 90.2 & 0.83 & 97.2 & 0.47 & 83.3\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=100$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=3$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=2$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\dotfill\tablenotemark{e}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=100$}
&\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
Student's $t$\tablenotemark{d} & 1 & 67.7 & 1 & 97.5 & 1 & 81.1 & \dotfill & \dotfill & 1 & 27.2\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=100$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=4$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=5$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=2$}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=61$}
&\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
Student's $t$\tablenotemark{d}& 0.85 & 99.4 & 1.11 & 99.7 & 1.50 & 99.9 & 1.28 & 99.9 & 0.75 & 97.9\\
\noalign{\vskip 1mm}
\enddata
\tablenotetext{a}{Scale factor...}
\tablenotetext{b}{This is the...}
\tablenotetext{c}{We use the...}
\tablenotetext{d}{We allow...}
\tablenotetext{e}{The K-S test...}
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

I have not been able to find the error and i have looked through as many similar questions as i could, all help is appreciated?!? It compiles with the same errors as when i use aastex v5.2 and v6.1..

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @MartinSchröder I have added my preamble and supplied the prior version i had compiled under, and made sure everything worked at least on ShareLatex.. (I am unfamiliar with TexMaker.)

Comment: `aastex61` is not a common class. Please make your example a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Do you know how to assist me in the error i am having?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
\\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
```

instead of

```
&\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{aastex61}
\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}llrlrlrlrlr}
\tablecaption{K-S Test Probabilities \label{table:KS}}
\tablewidth{0pc}
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablehead
{
\colhead{}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\mathrm{med}}_{\sigma}$}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\mathrm{Gott}}_{\sigma}$\  \tablenotemark{c}}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\mathrm{wm+}}_{\sigma}$}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\mathrm{wm-}}_{\sigma}$}&
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{$N^{\mathrm{mean}}_{\sigma}$} \\
\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
\colhead{PDF}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}& \colhead{$S$\tablenotemark{a}}& 
\colhead{P$(\%)$\tablenotemark{b}}
}
\startdata
Gaussian & 1 & 69.4 & 1 & 53.4 & 1 & 11.9 & 1 & 11.7 & 1 & 27.9\\
Gaussian & 0.85 & 99.5 & 1.24 & 99.6 & 1.68 & 99.9 & 1.73 & 99.8 & 0.76 & 97.9\\
Laplace & 1 & 39.0 & 1 & 82.6 & 1 & 47.9 & 1 & 45.3 & 1 & 19.7\\
Laplace & 0.77 & 93.6 & 1.13 & 97.7 & 1.40 & 99.8 & 1.52 & 99.9 & 0.70 & 90.4\\
Cauchy & 1 & 4.1 & 1 & 32.8 & 1 & 64.6 & 1 & 88.7 & 1 & 1.9\\
Cauchy & 0.51 & 84.6 & 0.70 & 84.8 & 0.77 & 90.2 & 0.83 & 97.2 & 0.47 & 83.3\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=100$}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=3$}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=2$}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\dotfill\tablenotemark{e}}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=100$}
\\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
Student's $t$\tablenotemark{d} & 1 & 67.7 & 1 & 97.5 & 1 & 81.1 & \dotfill & \dotfill & 1 & 27.2\\
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=100$}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=4$}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=5$}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=2$}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$n=61$}
\\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{6-7} \cline{8-9} \cline{10-11}
Student's $t$\tablenotemark{d}& 0.85 & 99.4 & 1.11 & 99.7 & 1.50 & 99.9 & 1.28 & 99.9 & 0.75 & 97.9\\
\enddata
\tablenotetext{a}{Scale factor...}
\tablenotetext{b}{This is the...}
\tablenotetext{c}{We use the...}
\tablenotetext{d}{We allow...}
\tablenotetext{e}{The K-S test...}
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\rm` has been deprecated for more than 20 years; in the context above, `\mathrm` should be used.

Comment: Also i see your edit, i will change my `\rm`'s.